# how can I change the logfile permssions for postgresql 8.4?

Tags: postgresql

I see that there is a log_file_mode that was introduced in either 9.0 or 9.1, but it is not available for PG 8.4.  How to people manage to give access to the logfiles to users other than the postgres user?

(I'm on RHEL 6.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options include:

- Upgrading
- A cron job that does a `chmod` of the logs
- Logging to syslog and using syslog facilities to control log access